# Run javascript function on loaded page

Tags: javascript

Very new to Javascript, so working on my first project. Attempting to run a script that gathers listing numbers, opens them in a URL and clicks an element on the loaded page. I can't get .click() to run on the resulting loaded page.

I've tried to set the logIn function to only run once the resulting page has loaded, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. AM I missing something basic?

```
var listingNum = prompt("Listing numbers").split(" ");

logIn = function(){
    if(document.readyState === "complete"){
        document.getElementById('SignInAsMemberLinkHeader').click();
    }
};

for(i = 0; i < listingNum.length; i++){
 window.open("http://www.website.com" + listingNum[i],"_self");

    setInterval(logIn(), 4000);
};
```

Comment: You can't run a script on a different website (or have a script on your own that interacts with it) unless you (illegally?) exploit a security vulnerability on their website. That's called XSS (cross-site scripting).

Comment: What is the URL meant to be doing with listingNum? There's no / or # character there, so the listingNum[i] will simply be directly appended to the end of the com part of the URL. Is this correct? Looks odd. In addition to the possible cross site scripting restrictions, you're also opening several windows, which you do nothing with, except trying to call logIn() on the CURRENT window after 4 seconds. Which will take you away from the page before the other windows can be opened. You could perhaps assign the returned window handle from window.open e.g. `var handle = window.open(url, etc);`

Comment: Apologies, I've missed a / at the end of the URL, which I took out when editing the URL for posting here. It's part of a small work project, so needed to keep the site to myself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the following test harness worked for me. I had to change your _self reference to _blank, so that each page loads separately and doesn't overwrite the operation of the parent page. You then just handle the load event of each window that is instantiated using window.open(). This was the part you were missing. You weren't handling the load events of the loaded windows.

You may wish to check that the SignInAsMemberLinkHeader element exists prior to calling click() on it, but I'll leave that up to you to implement.

**NB this will not work if cross site scripting restrictions apply.**

Hope this helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>External Page Opener Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:cornflowerblue;
                color:white;
                font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

            function init(event) {
                var listings = prompt("Listing numbers:");
                if (listings) {
                    var listingNum = listings.split(" ");
                    for (i = 0; i < listingNum.length; i++) {
                        // I used my local desktop and 3 test HTML files,
                        //each with a button click and handler on them.
                        var url = "file:///C:/Users/******/Desktop/" + listingNum[i];
                        var handle = window.open(url, "_blank");
                        handle.addEventListener('load', extPageLoaded, false);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('No listings were entered.');
                }
            }

            function extPageLoaded(event) {
                const TIME_TO_WAIT_IN_MILLISECONDS = 4000;
                setTimeout(
                    function() {
                        event.target.getElementById('SignInAsMemberLinkHeader').click();
                    },
                    TIME_TO_WAIT_IN_MILLISECONDS
                );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```